# Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ not both $0$ and $f(\vec{x})=ax_1+bx_2$ and $A= \{f(\vec{x}):\vec{x}\in B(\vec{0},1)\}$. Determine $\inf A$ and $\sup A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ not both $0$ and $f(\vec{x})=ax_1+bx_2$ and $A= \{f(\vec{x}):\vec{x}\in B(\vec{0},1)\}$. Determine $\inf A$ and $\sup A$ where $$B(\vec{0},1)=\{\vec{y}=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2: \sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}<1\}$$ and $\inf, \sup$ denote the infimum and supremum respectively.

By intuition, I think that the supremum and minimum would be the last and first intersection of the line $bx_1=ax_2$ with the circle of radius $1$ centered on $0,0$ respectively, but I don't know how to prove this or how to start to be honest. I will appreciate any help to solve this. Thanks in advance for reading

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @metamorphy I don't see how to use the inequality to be honest. I thought that I had to use some inequality but no idea of how to apply it

Comment: Further hint: if $\ \vec{u}=\frac{1}{\|(a,b)\|}(a,b)\in B(\vec{0},1)\ $, what are $\ f(\vec{u})\ $ and $\ f(-\vec{u})\ $?  Is there any $\ \vec{x}\in B(\vec{0},1)\ $, such that $\ f(\vec{x})> f(\vec{u})\ $?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera well, the normalized vector $\frac{(a, b)}{||(a, b)||}\not\in B(\vec{0}, 1)$ right? But I'll try it I think I get it now, thanks!

Comment: The only thing left is to see how it is, in fact, the supremum and infimum, but I don't know how to get the contradiction, I see that it is at least an upper bound but how can I prove that it is the minimum upper bound?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that your $\ B(\vec{0}.1)\ $ is the *open* unit ball.  Otherwise, I would have written $\ \vec{u}\in cl\left(B(\vec{0}.1)\right)\ $. You will need to make use of the fact (or equivalent) that there must be a sequence $\ \left\{y_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty\ $, $\ \vec{y_n}\in B(\vec{0}.1)\ $  such that $\ \lim \vec{y_n}=\vec{u}\ $.